# Vim delete all paragraphs with matching regex

Tags: vim

I have a series of paragraphs--a java thread dump--that I would like deleted but ONLY if the paragraphs contain the text /`Executor\.getTask`/ -- that is, the threads don't have a task.

How can I do this in vim? I'm currently have a macro with the contents `/Executor\.getTask^Mvipd` , but this means I have to press `@@` a couple thousand times -- it's a large thread dump. I hope there's a way to utilize `global` to do it.

Here's an example paragraph.

```
"xyz-1376" prio=10 tid=0x00002aedbc289000 nid=0x6cdf waiting on condition [0x00002aedd221f000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000434ca6d48> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `:global` and `:normal`:

```
:g/Executor\.getTask/norm dap
```

Comment: Gorgeous! I love it.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a good answer, using `:global`. But your original method could also work. Rather than pressing `@@` a couple thousand times, just give it a count: `999999@@`. The macro will automatically stop repeating when it encounters an error - in this case, when there are no more matches for your search string. If you don't want it to loop back to the beginning of the file, then you can `:set nowrapscan` first but in this case it doesn't look required.